# Pandas: monthly date range with number of days

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

Suppose I have a start and end dates like so:

```
start_d = datetime.date(2017, 7, 20)
end_d = datetime.date(2017, 9, 10)
```

I wish to obtain a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Month    NumDays
2017-07  12
2017-08  31
2017-09  10
```

It shows the number of days in each month that is contained in my range.

So far I can generate the monthly series with `pd.date_range(start_d, end_d, freq='MS')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) by default `day` frequency first, then create `Series` and [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.size.html). Last convert to `month` period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
import datetime as dt    

start_d = dt.date(2017, 7, 20)
end_d = dt.date(2017, 9, 10)

s = pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(start_d, end_d), dtype='float64')

df = s.resample('MS').size().rename_axis('Month').reset_index(name='NumDays')
df['Month'] = df['Month'].dt.to_period('m')
print (df)
    Month  NumDays
0 2017-07       12
1 2017-08       31
2 2017-09       10
```

Thank you [`Zero`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319852/pandas-monthly-date-range-with-number-of-days/46319991?noredirect=1#comment79600857_46319991) for simplifying solution:

```
df = s.resample('MS').size().to_period('m').rename_axis('Month').reset_index(name='NumDays')
```

Comment: This is realy nice

Comment: Awesome! And I'm using the following to obtain the total number of days in that month: `df['TotalDays'] = df['Month'].apply(lambda m: calendar.monthrange(m.year, m.month)[1])`

Comment: `df = s.resample('MS').size().to_period(freq='M').rename_axis('Month').reset_index(name='NumDays')` would be sufficient.

Comment: How would we do this in column format? Say df['begindate'], df['enddate'],  df['July'], df['Aug'], df['Sep'] ? - @jezrael