# Calculate days in a month given a date range (as pandas column)

Tags: pandas, datetime, group-by

This is a twist on a similar question regarding calculating range of days between two dates bucketed into monthly columns [Pandas: monthly date range with number of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319852/pandas-monthly-date-range-with-number-of-days).

In my dataframe I have two columns df['begin_date'] and df['end_date'].  I want to calculate how many days occur in specific months.

```
df['PTO_End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.PTO_End_Date)
df['PTO_Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.PTO_Start_Date)

df['Days'] = (df['PTO_End_Date'] - df['PTO_Start_Date']).dt.days
df['Feb-2023'] =
df['Mar-2023'] =
df['Apr-2023'] =
```

I can calculate the # of days between the dates, but the dates span over multiple months and I am trying to bucket the days into the specific month.  Looking for a way to convert this series style code into a panda column.

```
s = pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(df['PTO_Start_Date'], df['PTO_End_Date']), dtype='float64')
```

Answer (score 0):

@Arthur given the fact you have 100 records then it would be best to create a DataFrame for each record. While this requires more code. It is doable.

You can leverage several functions such as df.pipe() to pass functions. Here's how I solved it.

This example has 20 dates but it can scale to any number.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'start': [
            '2023-03-15', '2023-04-11', '2023-04-26', '2023-05-05', '2023-06-19',
            '2023-07-04', '2023-07-24', '2023-08-01', '2023-08-21', '2023-09-07'
        ],
        'end': [
            '2023-09-22', '2023-10-05', '2023-10-12', '2023-10-19', '2023-11-20',
            '2023-11-23', '2023-11-30', '2023-12-08', '2023-12-11', '2023-12-13'
        ]
})

def monthly_pto_days_per_range(start_date: str, end_date: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    dates = pd.Series(
        {"start": pd.to_datetime(start_date), "end": pd.to_datetime(end_date)}
    )
    return (
        (
            pd.Series(
                index=pd.date_range(start=dates["start"], end=dates["end"]),
                dtype="float64",
            )
            .resample("M")
            .size()
            .to_period("M")
            .to_frame()
            .T
        )
        .assign(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
    )


def col_to_front(df: pd.DataFrame, column: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    r"""
    Bring column to front in a DataFrame.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame

    col : str
        Column to move

    front : bool, optional
        by default True will bring column to position 0
        else to last column
    """
    return df.loc[
        :, lambda x: sorted(x.columns, key=lambda col: 0 if col == column else 1)
    ]

def generate_pto_days_from_date_ranges(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return (
        pd.concat(
            [
                np.vectorize(monthly_pto_days_per_range)(df["start"], df["end"])[i]
                for i in df.index
            ]
        )
        .fillna(0)
        .pipe(col_to_front, "end_date")
        .pipe(col_to_front, "start_date")
    )

dates_df.pipe(generate_pto_days_from_date_ranges)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a complete code here:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')
df.columns = [c.replace(' ','_') for c in df.columns]

# Select columns for dataframe
df = df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'PTO_Start_Date', 'PTO_End_Date']]

# Convert to datetime
df['PTO_Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.PTO_Start_Date)
df['PTO_End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.PTO_End_Date)

results = df.join(
    df.apply(lambda df: pd.Series(pd.date_range(df['PTO_Start_Date'], df['PTO_End_Date'], freq='B').to_period('M')), axis=1)
    .apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1)
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
)

df = results

df.to_csv('Newfile.csv', index=False)
```

This keeps all my original columns plus adds # Business Days per Month in their own columns.  Freq='B' for business days, Freq='D' for total days.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem with this code?